# Recursive SELECT query to return rates of arbitrary depth?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

This is my first time attempting a recursive SQL query to traverse N parent-child relationships upward, and I don't know where to start.  Any help would be appreciated.

Scenario is that I have two tables - `rate` and `rate_plan`.  Rates belong to a rate plan which is applied to a user.

```
CREATE TERM rate_plan (
   id                  integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
                       DEFAULT nextval('rate_plan_id'),

   descr               varchar(64) NOT NULL,

   parent_rate_plan_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES rate_plan(id)
);

CREATE TABLE rate (
   id                integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
                     DEFAULT nextval('rate_id'),

   prefix            varchar(24) NOT NULL,

   rate_plan_id      integer NOT NULL 
                     REFERENCES rate_plan(id)
);
```

A typical query to get a rate:

```
SELECT * FROM rate  
   WHERE (
      rate_plan_id = ${user rate plan ID} 
      AND prefix = ${prefix}
   )
   ORDER BY LENGTH(prefix) ASC;
```

What I would like is to return the most-specific (`LENGTH()`-iest prefix) rate, but not being limited to `${user rate plan ID}`, but instead picking rates from those affiliated with any number of rate plans in a `rate_plan.parent_rate_plan_id` hierarchy.  The recursion should bottom out when `rate_plan.parent_rate_plan_id = NULL`.

I would just do a `JOIN`, but I need to accommodate N parent-child relationships, not just two.

This is on PostgreSQL 9.x.  I tried `WITH RECURSIVE` and `UNION ALL`, joining `rate_plan` to `rate` on every `SELECT` and trying to filter by parent, but got nowhere, due to an inadequate understanding of how those constructs work.

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding what you're trying to do. But in the docs on CTEs, there's an example query for graphs, that builds a path of parent nodes using an array. Do the same for your tree: the query you want should then be (hopefully) obvious, e.g. every node whose parents include the node with your prefix, or whatever it is you're looking for exactly.

Comment: Could you prepare some sample data (a few inserts) and enter it into this sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/89073/1 ? Then attach a link to SQLFiddne, and explain please your requirements on the basis of this data and show expected results.

Comment: [Postgres major versions](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) include the first digit after the dot. The current version is *9.3*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for, according to your description:

> the most-specific (`LENGTH()`-iest prefix) rate, but not being limited
>   to `${user rate plan ID}`, but instead picking rates from those affiliated

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT id, parent_rate_plan_id
   FROM   rate_plan  
   WHERE  id = ${user rate plan ID} 

   UNION ALL
   SELECT rp.id, rp.parent_rate_plan_id
   FROM   cte
   JOIN   rate_plan rp ON rp.id = cte.parent_rate_plan_id
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte
JOIN   rate r ON r.rate_plan_id = cte.id
ODER   BY length(prefix) DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Recursion stops automatically as soon as the top node (`parent_rate_plan_id IS NULL`) is reached.

It's more effective to join to `rate` once after you have collected all plans.

[The manual on (recursive) CTEs.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html)

Comment: This seems to be the right idea;  however, Postgres won't let me run it as "WITH cte", complaining about it being self-referential.  But when I run it as WITH RECURSIVE, it seems to recurse infinitely.

Comment: I stand corrected;  I implemented your recommendation incorrectly.  This does indeed appear to do it!  Thank you.

Comment: @AlexBalashov: Added the missing `RECURSIVE` clause.