# Tree with recursive and default

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Using Postgres.

I have a `pricelists`

```
CREATE TABLE pricelists(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES pricelists
);
```

and another table, `prices`, referencing it

```
CREATE TABLE prices(
  pricelist_id INTEGER REFERENCES pricelists,
  name TEXT,
  value INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (pricelist_id, name)
);
```

- Parent pricelist `id=1` may have 10 prices.
- Pricelist `id=2` as a child of parent `1` may have 5 prices which override parent `1` prices of the same price name.
- Child Pricelist `id=3` as as a child of pricelist `2` may have 2 price which override child `2` prices of the same price name.

Thus when I ask for child `3` prices, I want to get

- all prices of child `3` and
- those prices of his parent (child `2`) that do not exists in child `3` and
- all parent `1` prices that do not exists until now.

The schema can be changed in order to be efficient.

#### Example:

If

```
SELECT pl.id AS id, pl.parent_id AS parent, p.name AS price_name, value
FROM pricelists pl
JOIN prices p ON pl.id = p.pricelist_id;
```

gives

```
| id       |      parent   |  price_name |     value   |  
|----------|:-------------:|------------:|------------:|  
| 1        |  1            | bb          |     10      |  
| 1        |  1            | cc          |     10      |  
| 2        |  1            | aa          |     20      |  
| 2        |  1            | bb          |     20      |  
| 3        |  2            | aa          |     30      |
```

then I'm looking for a way of fetching `pricelist_id = 3` prices that'd give me

```
| id       |      parent   |  price_name |     value   |  
|----------|:-------------:|------------:|------------:|  
| 1        |  1            | cc          |     10      |  
| 2        |  1            | bb          |     20      |  
| 3        |  2            | aa          |     30      |
```

Comment: Please, as *always*, provide your version of Postgres. `SELECT version()`. And show what you tried, even if it's not working.

Comment: Should pricelist `1` in the example really have itself as parent, rather than `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT id, name, parent_id, 1 AS lvl
   FROM   pricelists
   WHERE  id = 3  -- provide your id here

   UNION ALL
   SELECT pl.id, pl.name, pl.parent_id, c.lvl + 1
   FROM   cte  c
   JOIN   pricelists pl ON pl.id = c.parent_id
   )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.price_name)
       c.id, c.parent_id, p.price_name, p.value
FROM   cte c
JOIN   prices p ON p.pricelist_id = c.id
ORDER  BY p.price_name, c.lvl;  -- lower lvl beats higher level
```

- Use a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) like here:

  - [Total children values based on parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771646/total-children-values-based-on-parent/24772960#24772960)
  - [Recursive SELECT query to return rates of arbitrary depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593359/recursive-select-query-to-return-rates-of-arbitrary-depth/20594252#20594252)

  There are *many* related answers.
- Join to prices once at the end, that's cheaper.
- Use `DISTINCT ON` the get the "greatest per group":

  - [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: This query will not terminate if there are pricelists that have themselves as parents, as in the example given in the question. Though I [guess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627270/tree-with-recursive-and-default/29628116#comment47403258_29627270) this might either be a mistake in the example data or be covered by the "The schema can be changed in order to be efficient." phrase.

Comment: @das-g. That's correct. The base table should have a constraint `CHECK (id <> parent_id)`. and the root should have `parent_id` is `NULL`.

Comment: Ah, right, that should be part of the consistency requirements. I've proposed an edit to the question with that `CHECK`, even though it doesn't suffice to avoid loops in the pricelist directed graph in general.

Comment: @das-g: The `CHECK` constraint only rules out simple shortcut loops. all kinds of loops would violate a sane data model.

Comment: That's what I wanted to point out in my previous comment. I just said it too convoluted, I guess. :-P

Comment: CHECK (id <> parent_id) prevent the situation of id==parent in a single record. But can I also prevent a parent loop, Where accidentally a child is set as his parent's parent?

Comment: @ZAky: Not with basic tools. You would have to write a trigger function, that iterates the lineage and collects IDs along the way to detects an endless loop. Here is an implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671612/prevent-and-or-detect-cycles-in-postgres/26672812#26672812